# Karma can't format console log

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner

node.js(v0.10.25) and chrome(v48.0.2564.97) browser can format in console.log like below.

```
> console.log('value=%s', 'OK')
value=OK
```

But karma(v0.13.15) can't.

```
> console.log('value=%s', 'OK')
LOG: 'value=%s', 'OK'
```

Why? Is there some way to do also in karma?